# Getting rid of objects after using reflection

Tags: c#, object, memory, reflection

I've been trying to call a method with a string, but one side-effect is that a new object is created everytime I press the button. How can I get rid of this? I've tried using null, but no luck.

First attempt:

```
string methodName = cboOriginal.Text + "To" + cboConverted.Text;
Type numeralType = typeof(NumeralSystemConversion);
ConstructorInfo numeralConstructor = numeralType.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes);
object numeralObject = numeralConstructor.Invoke(new object[] { });

MethodInfo numeralMethod = numeralType.GetMethod(methodName);
object numeralValue = numeralMethod.Invoke(numeralObject, new object[] { txtOriginal.Text });

txtConverted.Text = numeralValue.ToString();

numeralType = null; numeralConstructor = null; numeralObject = null;
numeralMethod = null; numeralValue = null;
```

Second attempt:

```
string methodName = cboOriginal.Text + "To" + cboConverted.Text;
convert = typeof(NumeralSystemConversion).GetMethod(methodName).Invoke(typeof(NumeralSystemConversion).GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes).Invoke(new object[] { }), new object[] { txtOriginal.Text });
txtConverted.Text = convert.ToString();
convert = null;
```

The 'convert' object is created when the app starts. And NumeralSystemConversion is a class I have created, where the methods are located.

What I am seeing is that the memory usage in the Diagnostic Tools (Visual Studio 2015 Community) increase each time I press the button.

Comment: Add the language to the tags. It's not always obvious from the code.

Comment: You are actually creating several objects with this code: a couple of `string`s, a couple of `object` arrays, and possibly an implicit `StringBuilder` to do the concatenation.

Comment: Yes, I know, that's why I want to clean it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The biggest "clean-up" I see is to create the two `object` arrays once (at startup) and store them in member variables:

```
object[] param1 = new object[] { };
object[] param2 = new object[] { null };
```

Then in your method:

```
param2[0] = txtOriginal.Text;
convert = typeof(NumeralSystemConversion).GetMethod(methodName)
    .Invoke(typeof(NumeralSystemConversion).GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes)
    .Invoke(param1), param2);
param2[0] = null;
```

I don't think you can prevent it from creating `string`s. That's the cost of doing business, I'm afraid. What *might* help is to use an explicit `StringBuilder` as another class member:

```
StringBuilder methodNameBuilder = new StringBuilder();
```

And in your function:

```
methodNameBuilder.Clear();
methodNameBuilder.Append(cboOriginal.Text);
methodNameBuilder.Append("To");
methodNameBuilder.Append(cboConverted.Text);
string methodName = methodNameBuilder.ToString();
```

Finally, the memory increases you're seeing could just be garbage, in which case `GC.Collect();` should clean them up. But it's probably better just to leave it alone, in that case.

Comment: Sadly, didn't do much. I don't really see how I'm creating so many strings.. Shouldn't it just overwrite?

Comment: Yes, it should destroy the old ones and create new ones, unless something else is holding onto references.

Comment: I've added a line to clean up the reference inside `param2`.

Comment: I tried making it into a string with .ToString() and go around the whole object, but that was even worse.

Comment: Perhaps if you pasted exactly what you're seeing into the question, I (or someone else) could get a better idea of the situation?

Comment: Updated the description.

Comment: OK. Maybe what you're seeing is normal. Try sticking `GC.Collect();` at the end of your function and see what the memory does.

Comment: You're a darling, mate! :D

Comment: Edited with that and more tips.